# My program doesn't recognize .isdigit as True

Tags: python, boolean

In my program I want to check if the stroke symbol is a common digit (0-9)

.isnumeral works strange because it counts alphabeticals (a-z) as True, well then I lurked in and got that .isnumeral isn't actually searching exclusively for what I want - digits. And through the manual I found .isdigit but:

```py
dna = 'a3'
start = 0
end = 1
if dna[end].isdigit is True:
    print('Yes')
```

It's not working and 'Yes' isn't showing as expected.

Comment: remove "is True" and add isdigit().  isdigit() already returns True or False.

Comment: `if dna[end].isdigit():`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if dna[end].isdigit is True:`

`isdigit()` is a function, not an attribute.

You forgot the parentheses on the end, therefore you're referring to *the function object itself*, instead of the *result* of calling the function.

Comment: Doesn't a function object, being not empty, evaluates to True nonetheless ?

Comment: Function objects are _truthy_, but they do not have the exact value `True`.

Comment: So ``if function_name:`` would pass but not ``if function_name is True``, right ?

Comment: @MaximGi the function or method object is neither True not False, if you cast it to bool() it will become True tho.

Comment: @Davo how so?  `if sorted: print 1` does print 1.  Therefore the built-in function object `sorted` (and, presumably, all function objects) is a truth-like value.

Comment: @JohnGordon oh yeah, thats equivalent to `if sorted not in [0, None, False]:` no problems here

Answer (score 1):

You must actually call the `isdigit()` method:

```py
dna = 'a3'
start = 0
end = 1
if dna[end].isdigit():
    print('Yes')
```

This gives your expected answer, True.

If you do `dna[end].isdigit` it just gives an object `<built-in method isdigit of str object at address>` which won't evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

`dna[end].isdigit` in this case is referring to a `str.isdigit` function. 
If you do `print(type(dna[end].isdigit))` you will see what I mean.

To call the function instead, add paranthesis like this `if dna[end].isdigit():`

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- there's no need to compare to true, just use the result from isdigit()
- isdigit() is a function, which is *truthy* on its own, but does not equate to True

Check out the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) for more info.